# When sharing an image using Mail, how to prevent the resolution from being reduced?

Tags: ios, resolution, photo, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an app, which saves photos to the iOS photo library, and also lets user share, using `UIActivityViewController`.

I tried emailing myself the saved images using the Mail app, and also tried sharing the photo with myself by selecting Mail from the share pane.

Both images have **1920x1080** resolution, but the one which was programmatically saved is 1.5MB and has 96DPI, whereas the one that was shared is 200KB and has 72DPI.

Is there any way to use `UIActivityViewController` to let the user share a full-resolution image?